# Input coordinates in pdfminer and get results

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am trying to extract text in pdf miner by inputting co-ordinates, I have searched the internet but could not find any documentation or code relating to that.So far I have found a code that extracts text and outputs its co-ordinates.

```
LTTextBoxHorizontal
(317.564, 91.32756, 580.93228, 116.24235999999999)
SHOULD ANY OF THE ABOVE DESCRIBED POLICIES BE CANCELLED BEFORE
THE    EXPIRATION   DATE    THEREOF,    NOTICE   WILL   BE   DELIVERED   IN
ACCORDANCE   WITH   THE   POLICY   PROVISIONS.
```

This is one of the output co-ordinates and text that I have obtained. I also tried **pdfquery** but I have got a lots of error.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyquery-1.2.11-py2.7.egg\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 268, in __call__
    result = self._copy(*args, parent=self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyquery-1.2.11-py2.7.egg\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 253, in _copy
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyquery-1.2.11-py2.7.egg\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 239, in __init__
    xpath = self._css_to_xpath(selector)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyquery-1.2.11-py2.7.egg\pyquery\pyquery.py", line 249, in _css_to_xpath
    return self._translator.css_to_xpath(selector, prefix)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cssselect\xpath.py", line 192, in css_to_xpath
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cssselect\parser.py", line 355, in parse
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cssselect\parser.py", line 370, in parse_selector_group
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cssselect\parser.py", line 378, in parse_selector
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cssselect\parser.py", line 437, in parse_simple_selector
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cssselect\parser.py", line 535, in parse_attrib
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected string or ident, got <NUMBER '1' at 14>
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Answer (score 4):

That happens when you don't escape **pageid** value.

**Try:**

```
LTPage[pageid=\'1\']
```